# Mysql total amount (price) in cart from many tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I met what I believe is a very common problem with mysql and e-commerce shop ... though I can't find answer for this.

I've got shop which has not one product table but many ... for example in one shop  has vinyls, studio gear etc ... so we've got many tables with different product details ... the thing is I need to get total amount (price) of products in cart from many tables

```
public static function GetTotalAmount() {
    $params = array(
        ':cart_id' => self::GetCartId()
    );
    $sql = 'SELECT SUM(v.price) AS total_amount '.
            'FROM shopping_cart sc '.
            'INNER JOIN vinyl v '.
            'ON sc.product_id = v.id  AND sc.department_id = 1 '.
            'WHERE sc.cart_id = :cart_id AND sc.buy_now;';
    $v = DataBase::FetchOne($sql, $params);
    $sql = 'SELECT SUM(sg.price) AS total_amount '.
            'FROM shopping_cart sc '.
            'INNER JOIN studio_gear sg '.
            'ON sc.product_id = sg.id  AND sc.department_id = 2 '.
            'WHERE sc.cart_id = :cart_id AND sc.buy_now;';
    $sg = DataBase::FetchOne($sql, $params);
return $sg + $v;
}
```

As you might see I made this with ugly way .. maybe you can help me show how to get SUM() of possible N tables counted from N.price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL

```
 SELECT SUM(price) FROM ((SELECT SUM(price) as price FROM table1 WHERE ...) UNION ALL (SELECT SUM(price) as price FROM table2 WHERE ...) UNION ALL  ....)
```

A quick tip (if you can) - merge all the products tables into one table and operate on that (you'll also have to implement categories and custom attributes for products though). Otherwise you will have a mess when you add new shops.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will merge products in one table

Answer (score 0):

You can create a (materialized) view with just the necessary columns of the product tables, - `product_id` and `price`

Once you have the view (`vw_products`) you can just do an inner join of shopping cart table with the view and then get the sum.

```
SELECT sum(vw.price) FROM
shopping_cart sc INNER JOIN vw_products vw 
ON sc.product_id = vw.id and sc.department_id IN (1,2,...)
WHERE sc.cart_id = :cart_id AND sc.buy_now;
```

If you have many rows and if the prices don't change often (every few minutes) 
I would suggest creating a table and populating it with the result of above query.

Every day or after every change to price you can refresh this table.